# Jetpack Compose ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to open a link using intent and I get this error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=example.com }

```
@Composable
fun MeetingDetailRowWithLink(
    header: String,
    content: String
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val intent = remember {
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(content))
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
             .padding(10.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
    ) {
        Text(
            text = header,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        )

        Text(
            text = content,
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                }
        )
    }
}
```

The content is my uri in the form of string. This reusable composable is in the MeetingDetail composable which is in the Root composable (navigation graph). Root composable is in the MainActivity.

Comment: `Uri.parse(content)` -- your value for `content` seems to be invalid. This needs to be a valid `Uri`, not a domain name.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks.